# Did Jewish Men Always Have Beards Throughout History

Tags: minhag, history, beard

When did Jews start keeping their beards? Did Moshe's generation have beards?

What is the historical development behind this phenomenon?

Comment: Certainly in David's time, Jewish men had beards. When the Ammonites sheared off half of the beards of David's envoys, David told them to stay in Jericho until the other half of their beards grew back ([*Sh'mu'el* II 10:4,5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b10.htm#4)).

Comment: Not to mention the mentions of beards in the time of Moshe and Aharon (*Vayikra* [14:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0314.htm#9), [19:27](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm#27), [21:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0321.htm#5); *T'hillim* [133:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26d3.htm#2) regarding Aharon himself), David (cited above, and *Sh'mu'el* I [21:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a21.htm#14)), Y'sha'yahu (*Y'sha'ya* [7:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1007.htm#20), [15:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a21.htm#14))...

Comment: ...Yirm'yahu (*Yirm'yahu* [41:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1141.htm#5), [48:37](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1148.htm#37)), Y'chezkel (*Y'chezkel* [5:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1205.htm#1)), and Ezra (*Ezra* [9:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a09.htm#3)).

Comment: Some more examples: *Vayikra* [13:29](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0313.htm#29) (as will some of the earlier examples, regarding *tzara'as* "leprosy"), *Sh'mu'el* II [19:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b19.htm#25), and *Sh'mu'el* II [20:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b20.htm#9). And *Divrei HaYamim* I [19:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a19.htm#5) repeats the story with David's envoys.

Comment: Also, Yosef was "shaved" before his encounter with Pharaoh, suggesting that he had a beard beforehand (*B'reishis* [41:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0141.htm#14), unless this only means his hair was trimmed, such as is perhaps indicated by Onkelos - "וספר ושני כסותיה". See also [*Y'vamos* 88a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=88&format=text), "ואמר רב חסדא מלמד שיצא בלא חתימת זקן ובא בחתימת זקן").

Comment: @Fred those are enough comments to make an answer IMO. But.... did the Ramchal have a beard?

Comment: http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/01/beards-and-beardlessness-in-italian.html

Comment: http://bdld.info/2010/07/01/clean-shaven-kabbalists-crusades-and-censorship/

Comment: @Matt Scandalous! It's sounds like you have some good material for an answer yourself. If you write one up, feel free to incorporate some of the stuff in my comments towards the Tanach-era part of an answer, if you like.

Comment: @Fred I actually have more on the Ramchal, there's a whole essay about his beard (or lack thereof) in my (machon ofek) edition of mesilas yesharim. Apparently they stopped printing it though

Comment: Also note that Yosef's brothers did not recognize him and he recognized them because they had been old enough to have beards when he last saw them.

Comment: @Fred I second Matt's request that you post an answer.  Particularly your David example is evidence that they didn't just happen to have beards.

Answer (score 8):

I assume that most people, besides Jews, also had beards, since it is a natural phenomenon that male humans have beards. At some point in time it became common for many men to shave them, and as mentioned by @Danny Schoemann, this was inconvenient for most Jews, and is still frowned upon by many for halachic reasons, so they are still more prevalent in Orthodox circles, even in communities that do not have any particular objection to shaving.

Asking when Jews started wearing beards is like asking when the Greeks started going uncircumcised.

Answer (score 5):

The Torah commands us ([Vayikra 19:27](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00762.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L2)) not to use a razor on one's beard.

> לֹא תַקִּפוּ פְּאַת רֹאשְׁכֶם **וְלֹא תַשְׁחִית אֵת פְּאַת זְקָנֶךָ**: ‏

As a result, Jews can trim their beards but not shave them, as documented in Shulchan Aruch יורה דעה in  [סימן קפא - אסור גלוח הפאות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_27.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

> **י:** אֵינוֹ חַיָּב עַל הַשְׁחָתַת פְּאַת הַזָּקָן אֶלָּא בְּתַעַר, אֲבָל בְּמִסְפָּרַיִם מֻתָּר, אֲפִלּוּ כְּעֵין תַּעַר. ‏
>
> הגה: וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם נִזְהָרִים כְּשֶׁמִּסְתַפְּרִין בְּמִסְפָּרַיִם שֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה הֶקֵּף הַגִּלּוּחַ בַּחֵלֶק הָעֶלְיוֹן מִן הַמְסַפְּרוֹת וְלֹא בַּתַּחְתּוֹן, פֶּן יַעֲשֶׂה הַכֹּל עִם חֵלֶק הַתַּחְתּוֹן וְהָוֵי כְּתַעַר (ת''ה סִימָן רצ''ה)‏

Only "recently" were electric shavers invented that possibly bypass the prohibition of using a razor on one's beard.

Though  [chemical depilatories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_depilatory) existed in the olden days [[source]](http://www.skintherapyletter.com/fp/2013/9.2/3.html) they are generally foul in odor and messy to use and were probably not very popular.

So in all likelihood, Jews started growing beards in Moshe's time, as soon as they were commanded to stop shaving with razors. As to whether they trimmed them, that does not seem to be documented.

According to kabbalistic sources, apparently, there's a spiritual advantage to not cutting one's facial hairs. According to them, the righteous ones - even in Moshe's time - would not have trimmed their beards. (ibid  באר היטב ):

> והאר''י ז''ל לא היה מגלח כלל לא בתער ולא במספרים לא בשום מקום כלל זולת בשיער שעל השפה המעכב האכילה היה חותך במספרים. גם **היה נזהר שלא ליגע בזקנו שמא יעקר ח''ו ב' משערותיו ונמצא פוגם ועוקר צינור א' ח''ו**) אבל הש''ך תפס דברי הרב עיקר והבו דלא לוסיף על החומרא עכ''ל: ‏

Comment: You make a very bold assumption that the Jews did not use depilatories due to its smell. Are you an expert on  depilatories and the history of its usage?

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom - if you look carefully, you will see that I added a source for my "bold assumption", which was actually copied & pasted from the site.

Comment: why do you think the jews did not have beards in Egypt. Among Egyptians any representation of facial hair other than the stylized pharaonic beard is rare. [All the subdued enemies wear beards, possibly a sign of their being foreigners. Servants of the king are beardless and of smaller size than the pharaoh.](http://www.reshafim.org.il/ad/egypt/narmer/)

Comment: Chasam Sofer 159 OC

Comment: @hazoriz - that's fascinating! But you answered your own question. "Servants of the king are beardless"! The Jewish were precisely that! (After being enslaved they started multiplying to the size of a nation.)

Comment: Some scientists guess that the Jews had beards before they became slaves https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lm9ATLhkujY

Comment: @hazoriz - too long to watch, but I saw Joseph was clean shaven, so that undermines their credibility. :-)

Comment: www.haaretz.com/polopoly_fs/1.584914!/image/3531662601.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_640/3531662601.jpg

Comment: On minute 6:28, that is not his face only a filling what is above and below it the original statue

Answer (score 5):

To answer the title but not the body of your question, the Raddak who lived 1160–1235 in Narbonne, Provence, mentions that in his times in the lands where he lived the minhag was to not keep a beard. See Samuel 2 10 5. In fact his words there are apologetically trying to explain why in Dovid's times, when everyone had beards, it was embarrassing not to have a beard.

Answer (score 1):

the Meam Loez in Bereishis says the lion, as king of the animals, was given a beard to give him a majestic look.

Likewise we can say for man who is the crown glory of creation and the one God chose for His service.

So according to this, it is proper for all men to have beards so it probably started from the first man (Adam) and was later contested by those who wished to deny the importance of man.